# How change UTF-8 code point case during commit Git?

Tags: git, utf

I want to commit UTF file with following text:

```
Session expir\u00e9!
```

But the previous version was:

```
Session expir\u00E9!
```

Simple case difference occurs a lot of times because my text editor and IDE save in lower case, but new file must be commited in UPPER case.

How I can fix this with GIT or may be some another tool (may be in IDE or text editor)?

Comment: Please show hexdump of your text - I think you are confusing `UTF-8` representation of your text with visible textual representation. On Linux, you can use utility `hexdump` to get hex dump of your data

Comment: "Session expirée" is visible text. But if commit it see "Session expir\u00e9!" or "Session expir\u00E9!". The problem is gerrit do not show the representation it show the codes and mark case difference in they.

Comment: Please `git show --stat <bad_commit> | hexdump -C ` and show relevant portion. It may be not git problem, but gerrit display issue.

Comment: It os not git problem, I asked - can git fix this when commit happens or not?

Comment: I don't think this is git problem, but I cannot tell with 100% certainty until I see hexdump of your commit message. If you want an answer, please provide hexdump.